# Parse server - File not found

Tags: mongodb, parse-server

Parse server version: 2.8.4

Parse dashboard version: 1.2.0

MongoDB version: 4.0.2

Hosting service: DigitalOcean

=================================

I'm transferring my app to a new Parse server and a new MongoDB server.
Everything works fine except the fact that I can't load any images! The content is being fetched properly, but the images don't load. Neither from the app, nor from the dashboard. (I get the `File not found.` there)

Here's how I transferred my db:
`mongodump --host sourceIP -d dbName --port 27017`

and then to load it:
`mongorestore --db dbName dbDir --username “username” —password "password" --authenticationDatabase "admin"`

I did a `db.fs.files.find()` and the images seem to be there just fine!

I also tried uploading a new image file and got the error:
`error 130. Could not store file.`

I believe that this is a db-side issue, because I tested the parse server with another MongoDB I have and it was working!

I also tried creating a new droplet and redo everything, but it didn't fix it!

Any suggestions?

Comment: The UX for saving and serving images is part of the Parse server, not MongoDB. If your Parse server works with another MongoDB instance, there must be some difference in the configuration or user permissions. Does Parse Server definitely save all images in MongoDB via GridFS, or could there perhaps be images saved on the filesystem as well?

Comment: Hello @Stennie and thanks for helping me! I don't think there are any images stored in my Parse server, but how can I know for sure?

Comment: I just tried removing the indexes of a collection, in case it was a compatibility issue, but to no avail! When you say it could be a `user permissions` what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent 2.5 days of my life, full of stress, just because I had the symbol `&` in my auth password, inside my `databaseURI`! For some reason, it doesn't affect fetching the data but it does affect fetching images!